# Нужно ли тут тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Фраза из сказки: "Не пей, Иванушка, (-) козленочком станешь" - нужно ли тире после "Иванушки"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире возможно, но не обязательно. Как и всегда в подобных случаях, когда тире несёт более стилистическую, чем грамматическую нрагрузку.
Тут скорее сложности с обоснованием запятой после "Иванушка" в случае постановки тире. Четкой и однозначной рекомендации нужно ли её опускать или сохранять перед тире в конкретном случае (обособление обращения) я не знаю. Но это отдельный разговор.

Comment: Почему же, обращение обязательно должно быть обособлено запятыми с обеих сторон. Так что запятая само собой, и тире на постановку запятой не должно влиять.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @__inna__  в том, что тире не влияет на запятую.

Comment: >>>Почему же, обращение ("Иванушка") обязательно нужно выделить запятыми с обеих сторон.   

Вот и я хотел бы увидеть **почему же**. Явным образом написанное. 
Перед точкой или в начале фразы вы будете с двух сторон "выделять"?
Перед скобкой или точкой с запятой? 
Две щапятые подряд не буледе ставить?   А ведь в данном случае тире поставлено **вместо запятой**.

Comment: ЗЫ Вопрос, грубо говоря, в том, берет ли на себя тире 
роль второй запятой в той или иной обособляемой конструкции. Причем этот вопрос может разрешаться по-разному в зависимости от контекста и смысла конретной обособляемой части. И решать его методом голого утверждения "обязательно надо с двух сторон" как-то не комильфо.

Comment: У нас конкретный пример, и мое мнение об обязательности запятой касается только этого конкретного примера.

Answer (score 2):

То, что тире в это предложении факультативно - все согласны. Возник вопрос о запятой: если ставим тире, то нужна ли запятая, закрывающая обращение (или любую другую конструкцию)?

Запятая нужна. Не ломаем копья (как сказал  behemothus , не наш уровень), а снова внимательно читаем правила русской орфографии и пунктуации в разделе "Сочетание знаков препинания,...взаимодействие знаков в сложных конструкциях" и принимаем как данность.

**При сочетании в тексте тире и запятой вначале ставится запятая (запятая закрывает впереди стоящую конструкцию), затем тире.**

Такую же формулировку встретим и в других пособиях и справочниках.

ВОзможно, если поискать подольше в научных трудах, найдутся сведения и о том, что тире может поглощать запятую. Но в нормативных справочниках, учебниках для школьников говорится о том, что при встрече тире и запятой ставятся оба знака, каждый на своем основании.

Comment: Согласна, нет никаких причин для того, чтобы не ставить в данном примере запятую. Если бы в пунктуации были прописаны правила поглощения одного знака другим, это сильно бы усложнило и без того непростой русский язык, как мне кажется.

Comment: На самом деле случаи поглощения одного знака другим есть. Если встречаются запятая и двоеточие - ставится только двоеточие. Но при встрече запятой и тире  обычно этого не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Возможны варианты с тире и без (на выбор автора). Наличие тире подчеркнет причину-следствие.